# Django - NameError: name 'app1' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have just set up virtualenv and then created a new app, called "app1", under a new project, "devp1".  I have edited the files as the following:

views.py in in "app1" dir

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("wow my first page")
```

settings.py in "devp1" dir

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app1',
]
```

url.py in "devp1" dir

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'','app1.views.home'),
]
```

However, when I run the server, I receiving the following error, I have not found why it is not able to see "app1".

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f7ab830b400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/usr1/dev/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/usr1/dev/devp1/devp1/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'', app1.views.home),
    NameError: name 'app1' is not defined
```

Comment: The code in the traceback does not match the code you posted from urls.py.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail?  I am new to Django and Python. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with being new. The code you've posted isn't the code you're running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the quotation marks aren't in your views. The traceback shows

```
url(r'', app1.views.home),
```

but your urls.py file shows

```
url(r'','app1.views.home'),
```

Without those quotes it won't find the view in your application. I also don't think your regex will work the way you want it to. I would try this instead:

```
from app1 import views as app1_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', app1_views.home, name='home'),
]
```